# Is Microsoft serious about XBAP?

Tags: wpf, firefox, xbap

As a developer, can I count on XBAP? or is Microsoft slowly removing support in favor of Silverlight?

One of the selling points of XBAP is multi browser support (IE and Firefox).

However, the Firefox add-in for XBAP is not in the .NET 4.0 install.

I understand there was a security issue but this has been a while and Microsoft has not released any new add-in.

Comment: Not a bad question I think. Hard to say what Microsoft's intentions are, though. To me, the logical choice would be Silverlight these days.

Comment: I would say it's a genuine question. It can however be made a community wiki.